# FCM considered external network on Cloud Functions for Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

I am getting an error stating external network is not accessible, which makes sense as I am on the free tier of Firebase. But I thought Firebase services were included in the free tier, and as such, I should be able to use FCM.

Here is the code I am using for my index.js for the functions.

```
var functions = require('firebase-functions');
var admin = require("firebase-admin");

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.buttonPress = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    let testToken = "TOKEN";
    let payload = {
        data: {
            type: req.body.type
        }
    };
    admin.messaging().sendToDevice(testToken, payload)
        .then(function (response) {
            ...
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            ...
        });
});
```

Comment: Could you please paste the exact errors that you see in the logs?

Comment: @Nivco

2017-04-04T20:41:37.499893555Z D buttonPress: Function execution started
2017-04-04T20:41:37.500149858Z D buttonPress: Billing account not configured. External network is not accessible and quotas are severely limited. Configure billing account to remove these restrictions
2017-04-04T20:41:38.253717124Z D buttonPress: Function execution took 755 ms, finished with status code: 304

Comment: As Puf wrote below (in the answer) this is not an error but showed on every bilingless project. It looks like your function terminated properly so... everything is fine ? :D

Comment: The FCM message is never sent. It works fine from a node server, but when using the cloud function, it won't send.

Comment: For free tire account, FCM is not considered as an external network on Cloud Functions its just working fine. That is just a warning. you can ignore it, as they are working on it to not to show.

Answer (score 1):

*firebaser here*

> Billing account not configured. External network is not accessible and quotas are severily limited. Configure billing account to remove these restrictions.

This message now shows up for any Cloud Functions that are invoked from projects that are on the free tier. It doesn't mean that any calls have actively been blocked, just they calls to *external services* will be blocked for this project.

We're looking if we can get the message removed.

Comment: I do not understand. Does this mean that free tier cannot make use of functions? Or am I missing something?

Comment: I actually just noticed this exact issue myself. I'm utilizing the firebase-admin auth() functionality, but anytime I try to make an http request to my function, I get this exact error. I thought this type of functionality was free on the free tier :/

Comment: @abarax the free tier can make use of functions to handle incoming traffic and to make calls to other Firebase and Google services. The only thing that is not possible on the free plan (aside from the quota limits) is calling into external HTTP services. The reason for that limitation is to prevent abuse.

Comment: I am getting this message randomly on free tier, though I am not calling any external services. What could be the reason ?

Answer (score -1):

For Free tier account, Firebase has imposed a restriction on accessing external service that is not within google's network.

To get to the root cause of the problem just go to the Firebase console and check your functions's log. The log will show exactly what service or packages you installed is trying to make external HTTP request.

Comment: For free tire account, FCM is not considered as an external network on Cloud Functions its just working fine.
That is just a warning. you can ignore it, as they are working on it to not to show.

Comment: @JahangirKabir I never said FCM as external network. What I meant to say was to check the firebase console and determine if there are any other packages that OP added that was trying to make external HTTP request.

 I did however misread the OP question (I thought he misread the error of some other packages with FCM)

Answer (score -1):

To sent FCM through cloud functions, you can use the code below.
Check log if you are getting right tokens.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

exports.sendNotification = functions.firestore
.document('/users/{documentId}')
.onWrite((change, context) => {
   console.log("DOCUMENT ID : " + context.params.documentId);

   //Get all data 

   const payload = {
            notification: {
              title: 'Test title!',
              body: `${userName} sent you a following request.`
              // icon: follower.photoURL
            }
          };

    admin.messaging().sendToDevice(followedFCMToken, payload)
        .then(function (response) {
            console.log("Push response : " + response);
            return response
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.error("Error in sending push");
        });
});
```